# Manipulate CSS with javascript

Tags: css

RE:http://www.jorgemonedero.com/blog/index.php/portfolio/tamara-rojo-2/

I wish to move the close button (top right below social media icons) to the bottom line alongside photo title/publication and photo count. When I changed the css the button disappears behind a layer?
Someone mentioned I could do this with javascript?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't see a close button....

Comment: Why don't you just modify the HTML and put the close button inside the .preview-content element, then redo the style accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Brians answer is pretty much the easiest way to go, or you could give your container #grid-gallery-wrapper a height and then it wouldn't cut off the close buttons when positioned.